# C# - Calling unmanaged function with a fixed size out parameter

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I've been searching for the last 12 hours or so and don't think I'm even on the right track at this point or if I'm wording my searches properly. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

I'm attempting to access a function in an unmanaged library that takes as one of it's parameters a fixed size DWORD array and I'm not sure how to specify this in the declaration or call. I'm also not sure if the documentation for the function is correct (or if I understand it).

> `int EloGetScreenInfo(DWORD dwMonNum[32], int iScrCnt)`
>
> Parameters: 
>   `dwMonNum [in]`: Array of DWORD to receive the Windows monitor number associated with the  touchscreens.
>
> `iScrCnt [out]`: It retrieves the total number of Elo touchscreens found.
>
> Return Values: Returns EloSuccess if the call succeeds, it returns an error code otherwise. See Error Codes section for list of error values.
>
> Remarks:
>
> It returns the list of Windows monitor numbers associated with the touchscreens where,  the index is the touchscreen number and the value is the Windows monitor number.
>
> Touchscreens are 0 based and Windows monitor numbers are 1 based.
>
> If a touchscreen is not calibrated, the windows monitor is returned as -1.
>
> Maximum of 32 touchscreens are supported.

Notice in the description it states that it returns a list of monitor numbers which would suggest that it would be the populated value, yet in the parameter descriptions it shows that as an `[in]` and the count parameter as an `[out]` unless i'm misinterpreting the descriptions. 
In a See Also Sample link it shows an example of usage in which both seem to be populated

```
    DWORD dwEnumMon[MAX_SUPPORTED_SCR] ;
    int iScrCnt, iRet ;

    ZeroMemory( dwEnumMon, MAX_SUPPORTED_SCR ) ;
    ZeroMemory( dwMonParam, MAX_SUPPORTED_SCR ) ;

    // Get the list of all Elo Serial & USB screen and monitor association
    iRet = EloGetScreenInfo(dwEnumMon,iScrCnt) ;
    if(iRet != EloSuccess ){
        printf( "Error Code = %d \n", iRet ) ;
        return EloFailure;
    }
    else
    if(iScrCnt<0){
        printf( "No Elo touchscreens found\n" ) ;
        return EloFailure;
    }

    // Process Commandline
    ProcessCmdLine( argc, argv ) ;

    // For all screens of matching monitor number enable / disable touch
    for( int i=0; i<dwMonParamCnt; i++ ){
        // where j is the screen number associated with the monitor number
        for( int j=0; j<iScrCnt; j++ ){
            if( dwMonParam[i] == dwEnumMon[j] ){
                // Enables / Disables touch depending on the bFlag
                // where j is the screen number
                if( (iRet = EloSetTouchReportingState( bEnable , j )) == EloSuccess )
                    printf( "EloSetTouchReportingState Returned success\n" );
                else
                    printf( "EloSetTouchReportingState Returned failed. Error \ Code=%d\n", iRet );
               }
           }
      }

      return EloSuccess;
```

TIA for any direction or help you can provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call this with a normal array of `UInt32`. Your managed prototype would be:

```
[DLLImport "DllName"]
static extern int EloGetScreenInfo(UInt32[] dwMonNum, out int iScrCnt);
```

And to call it, just specify the marshaling:

```
UInt32[] MonitorNumbers = new UInt32[32];
int iScrCnt = 0;

int rslt = EloGetScreenInfo(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=32)] MonitorNumbers,
    out iScrCnt);
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer as mine, isn't it? Yours is more complete though, I didn't add the iScrCnt parameter.

Comment: Thank you both, Unless I misunderstood your call example it was a mixture of the two answers that turned out to be correct. in your example you show the MarshalAs which doesn't compile as it is not appropriate in that context, it needed to be specified in unmanaged function declaration as lesderid provided but it didn't need to be a DWORD. Thank you both!

Comment: @lesderid: Yes. I didn't see yours until after I'd posted mine.

Comment: @Josh: That's what I get for not testing. Glad you figured it out in spite of my mistake.

Comment: @JoshHetland: Glad I could help. Next time it might be better (faster for you) to first search on MSDN. Many problems that someone may have about using DLLs or even just C# are solved and explained very clear there.

Comment: @lesderid I did do some searching beforehand, and in fact I actually read the article you linked to in your answer, I didn't understand it though apparently =-) I'm going to go reread it again and see if i can figure out how you came to the solution you posted from it to better understand.

Comment: @Either of you: Testing it out i noticed that it is taking the array as a standard parameter and the int as an [out]; so how did the array get populated with information? is it ref by default?

Comment: @JoshHetland: This: "UInt32[] MonitorNumbers = new UInt32[32];" creates an array with 32 elements, and since UInt32 is a value-type, each element is set to "default(UInt32)", which is 0.

Comment: @lesderid: When i call the function passing MonitorNumbers the values of the elements within the array are changed to reflect the screen info (for instance on my test machine MonitorNumbers[0] = 1 after the call instead of it's default 0) How did the function change the values in the MonitorNumbers array?

Comment: @JoshHetland: Well, arrays are passed by reference (they are actually pointers in C++), not by value, so the the function you call can change the values of the elements of the array. (Sorry for the late reply...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4240/discussion-between-lesderid-and-joshhetland)

Answer (score 1):

This is what [MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx):

```
using DWORD = System.UInt32;

int YourUnmanagedFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=32)] DWORD[] array);
```

Comment: (Late) Note: DWORD isn't necessary, I only added it for the function declaration to resemble the C++ function as much as possible.